# PyQt combobox, extracting data on user pick

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Im trying to access current item from an qcombobox.

I have created a combobox with dynamic items from a list.

```
self.combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
for itm in self.ctpc:
    itms = str(itm)
    # [1:-2] removes '<' and '>' from beginning and end
    self.combo.addItem(itms[1:-1], userData=unicode(itm))

    print itm
    print ("cut_items_ordered: ", itm.cut_items_ordered)
    print ("Version: {} \n".format(itm.version))
```

self.ctpc include.

```
[<Cut Sequence 1>, <Cut simpans>, <Cut 20_sec>, <Cut test>]´
```

And depnding on what the user pick. I want to grab the ´cut_items_ordered´ from the relevant cut.
But im not sure on how to link up the data when the button is pressed.

cut_items_order is for example from  list contaning alot of clips:

```
[<CutItem A012C012_161202_R0FS>, <CutItem A019C007_161203_R0FS>, <CutItem A009C003_161202_R0FS>])
```

When "OK" is pressed:

```
for i in range(self.combo.count()): 
        itmData = self.combo.itemData(i)

    comboIndex = self.combo.currentIndex()

    if comboIndex == itmData:
        print self.combo.currentText()
```

Edit:

New code looks like,

```
    for itm in self.ctpc:
        self.itms = str(itm)
        # [1:-2] removes '<' and '>' from beginning and end
        self.combo.insertItem(0, self.itms[1:-1])
        self.combo.setItemData(0, unicode(itm))
        self.combo.setItemData(0, unicode(itm.cut_items_ordered))
        self.combo.setItemData(0, unicode(itm.version))
```

And later on on button press ( its connected to a func btn_accepted)

```
def btn_accepted(self)
    for i in range(self.combo.count()):
        self.itmData = self.combo.itemData(self.combo.currentIndex())               
    print self.itmData
```

Here i want to be able to access for example all data in itm.cut_items_orderd by it self and version by it self.

Comment: You can get the current text of a combo box via `currentText()`. The current data is received via `itemAt(currentIndex())`. PyQt5 has a shortcut for that: `currentData()`.

Comment: Thanks, @a_guest I will have a look at it when I'm back at the proper computer.

Comment: Hi again @a_guest. that worked great. but is it a way to add several data for a specific item. self.combo.insertItem(0, self.itms[1:-1])
                              self.combo.setItemData(0, unicode(itm))   self.combo.setItemData(0, unicode(itm.cut_items_order)) and later on access specific data?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Could you be more specific please? If you want to react on button presses you can connect their `clicked` event to a custom function: `button.clicked.connect(custom_function)`. Or pass the slot to the init method: `QPushButton(..., clicked=custom_function)`.